# How to get the input and output channels in a CNN?

Tags: image-processing, filter, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am specifically looking at the AlexNet architecture found here:
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/alexnet.py

I am confused as to how they are getting the input and output channels. Based on my readings of the AlexNet, I can't figure out where they are getting *outputchannels = 64* from (as the second argument to the `Conv2d` function). Even if the *256* is split across 2 GPUs, that should give *128* rather than *64*. The input channel of 3 initially represents the color channels as per my assumption. However, the other input and output channels don't make sense to me either.

Could anyone clarify what the input and output channels are?

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2), #why 64?
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `3` is the number of input channels (`R`, `G`, `B`). That `64` is the number of channels (i.e. *feature maps*) in the output of the first convolution operation. So, the first conv layer takes a color (RGB) image as input, applies `11x11` kernel with a stride 4, and outputs `64` feature maps.

I agree that this is different from the number of channels (`96`, 48 in each GPU) in the architecture diagram (of original AlexNet implementation).

However, PyTorch does not implement the original Alexnet architecture. Rather it implements a variant of the AlexNet implementation described in the paper: [`One weird trick for parallelizing convolutional neural networks`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5997).

Also, see [cs231n - convolutional networks](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) for more details about how input, filters, stride, and padding equates to output after the conv operation.

---

P.S: See [`pytorch/vision/issues/185`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/185)

Comment: Can you detail how we know that it outputs 64 feature maps? Is there a formula we can apply to get this information? I read in another resource that 64 is the number of filters we are using;is this the same thing?

Comment: precisely @ce1, we set the number of filters as output channels, in this case, 64.